# How to prove $x/2 > 2\log_2(x) +3$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality

For sufficient large $x,  x/2 > k \log_2(x) $, here $k$ is conatant  but How can I show this rigorously?

The main problem is to show:  $x/2 > 2\log_2(x) +3$ after a sufficient large $x=x_0$, how can I prove this?

Comment: Number theory?  Calculus seems easier.  With $f(x)=\frac 12 x -2\log_2(x)-3$ can you show that $f(x)$ is, eventually, increasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} - 2 \log_2(x) -3$

We have $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{x\ln(2)}$

So, for $x> \frac{4}{\ln(2)}, f'(x) > 0$. This imply that $f$ is increasing for $x> \frac{4}{\ln(2)}$

But $f(30) = 15 - 2 \log_2(30)-3>0$, hence, $\forall x > 30, \frac{x}{2} > 2\log_2(x)+3$

Answer (score 2):

First, look at the derivatives of each side of the reduced inequality: $\frac x2$ to $\frac12$, $2\log_2x+3$ to $\frac2{x\ln2}$. Clearly $\frac12>\frac2{32\ln2}$, so $\frac x2$ grows faster than $2\log_2x+3$ for $x>32$. Both these functions are strictly increasing, and the reduced inequality holds for $x=32$, so the reduced inequality, and thus the original inequality, must hold for sufficiently large *x*.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=\log_2(x)$ is concave and the line $g(x)=\frac x2$ cuts $f$ in the two points $(2,1)$ and $(4,2)$. It follows that for all $x\gt 4$ one has 
$$\log_2(x)\lt \frac x2$$ You can take many examples for $x_0$ and $k$, for example $x_0=16$ so you have $\log_2(16)=4$ and $\frac{16}{2}=8\gt4+3$, hence for $x\gt 16$ you can take $k=1$